# Nodejs on multiple servers files

Tags: node.js

I've 3 servers running nodejs, 4th server for ngninx load balancer (reverse proxy) and front-end code. everything works perfectly, but i want to manage file uploads. how i can manage this under this infastructure?

for example: if one of these 3 nodejs server uploads file on same server, how can i access this file?

nodejs servers are under example.com/api link, but becaouse of reverse proxy request goes to one server and i dont know on which server is particular file.

should i upload file to all nodejs servers?

Comment: Two options:
Use MongoDB GridFS storage - It allows to store large files as binary
Use a pub-sub/broker/messenger/queue such as Redis and maintain a file to server map and query this Redis to find the server on which the file resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have three separate node.js servers that are physically on separate servers with their own storage, then the usual way to share access to files is to have some shared storage that all three servers can access and then when any node.js server takes a file upload, it puts the data on the shared storage where everyone can access it.

If your three separate node.js servers are just separate processes on the same box, then they can all already access the same disk storage.

When sharing storage form separate processes or servers, you will have to make sure that your file management code is concurrency-safe - proper file locking when writing, concurrency-safe mechanisms for generating unique file names, safe caching, etc...

Or, you could use a database server for storage that all node.js servers have access to, though if you're just storing data files and don't have lots of meta data associated with them that you want to query and shared file system access is all you really need, then a database may not be the most efficient means of storing the data.

> should i upload file to all nodejs servers?

Usually not since that's just not very efficient.  Typically, you would upload once to a shared storage location or server or database that all servers can access.